# How does the Vulkan Validation Layer assignment work?

Tags: c++, callback, vulkan, validation-layers

I have started with Vulkan and just did the [Validation Layers](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Validation_layers).
In here, they add a static function `static VKAPI_ATTR VkBool32 VKAPI_CALL debugCallback(...)` to the .cpp file, then simply assign

```
createInfo.pfnUserCallback = debugCallback;
```

How (/why) does this work? I know of callbacks of course, but I tried to add this function to my renderer class instead of just "locally"(?) in the .cpp file, first in the header file:

```
static VKAPI_ATTR VkBool32 VKAPI_CALL DebugCallback(
VkDebugUtilsMessageSeverityFlagBitsEXT messageSeverity,
VkDebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagsEXT messageType,
const VkDebugUtilsMessengerCallbackDataEXT* callbackData,
void* pUserData);
```

And then in the .cpp file:

```
VKAPI_ATTR VkBool32 VKAPI_CALL VulkanRenderer::DebugCallback(
VkDebugUtilsMessageSeverityFlagBitsEXT messageSeverity,
VkDebugUtilsMessageTypeFlagsEXT messageType,
const VkDebugUtilsMessengerCallbackDataEXT* callbackData,
void* pUserData)
{
    //...
}
```

And finally using assigning it like this:

```
createInfo.pfnUserCallback = &VulkanRenderer::DebugCallback;
```

My version does in fact not work, so I probably am thinking about the wrong thing here. But I don't know what they did in the tutorial or even what to search for to understand this.

I do know what code to write to make it work like they have it, I just don't know why.

Comment: _"Doesn't work"_ still isn't an appropriate problem description here, _"in fact"_ or not.

Comment: I didn't write "it doesn't work" once anywhere. My problem is clearly one of not knowing about / understanding a feature. I state that I don't need a solution to the code part of the problem. I don't know what else I should write to make it appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `DebugCallback` is a non-static member function, then `&VulkanRenderer::DebugCallback` is a member function pointer.

A member function pointer is not a function pointer, but `pfnUserCallback` wants a function pointer.

Member function pointers and function pointers can't work the same because a non-static member function needs to know on which object it is being called, which isn't the case for a free function.

Now, Vulkan is a C API, not a C++ API, so it isn't aware of member functions at all and also uses a C idiom to implement the callback interface instead of a C++ one.

The C idiom however still allows passing information about the object on which you want to call your member function. That's what `pUserData` is for. It will be passed through unchanged to your callback and the callback can use it to e.g. do a member function call:

```
createInfo.pUserData = this;
createInfo.pfnUserCallback = [](auto a, auto b, auto c, void* pUserData){ return static_cast<VulkanRenderer*>(pUserData)->DebugCallback(a, b, c); };
```

(capture-less generic lamdbas can be converted into function pointers for specific argument types.)

(I don't actually know much about Vulkan. If `VKAPI_CALL` and `VKAPI_ATTR` are required on the function that will be called by Vulkan, then a lambda might not work. In that case use a static member function with a name on which you can apply the macros instead of an nameless lambda on which you likely can't.)

---

Alternatively, if `DebugCallback` doesn't need to be non-static, you can of course also declare it as `static` member function. Then your approach will also work. A static member function doesn't need any additional information about an object on which it is called and therefore forms normal function pointers like free functions.

Comment: `When DebugCallback is a non-static member function, then &VulkanRenderer::DebugCallback is a member function pointer.` - yes. Sorry, that was a copy and paste error on my part when asking the question. I went back and forth in the code a bit to try it, obviously I missed readding the `static` for the question. Thanks for the additional info!

Comment: @Tare But then I don't know what your problem is. A static member function behaves just like a free function.

Comment: My problem was apperantly a human error. I'm not sure what I did wrong before, it works now as you suggest (and I at least thought I tried).